# How to debug a java application when a value entered from UI is not persisted into the database?

Tags: java

Can someone explain me how to debug a java application in eclipse,when a value entered from U.I is not persisted in the database?

Comment: I think you need more details on what you mean by from UI. In general you would debug server side code in eclipse. You need to use a browser to debug front end code, ie Java Script.

Comment: If you cannot debug the application in some environments e.g. production, at least add proper logging messages to your operations so you can see what's happening.

Comment: If you have some kind of REST API or session bean you could create a unit test that calls the API method

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `Logger` and log out some of the values before inserting them into the database. If the values are logged out as `null`, then you will know that the value entered from the User Interface was not correctly sent over to your server side.

Comment: thank u for ur response @hev1

Comment: @Alekya No problem. If you have any questions, feel free to ask.